# Best way to create a multi relational database in my scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, software-design

I'm having trouble to develop my database model.

I have the tables TOUR and TRIP (both with GUID primary key) and both have some children tables in common. Like DETAIL, COMMENT, MEDIA, PRICE and like that.

I'm thinking in create in those children tables some "ParentId" column to link with TOUR or TRIP, but I need to know which parent table is. In this way I should to create a column "ParentType" where 1 is TOUR and 2 is TRIP or maybe create a TourDetail and a TripDetail to link each one with other table?

I'm looking for the best practice to do that.

Comment: When you do queries are TOUR and TRIP treated separately?

Comment: Yes, each one have his own columns.

Comment: When you are doing queries, are you going to be trying to aggregate TOUR and TRIP tables? As an example, is a query going to be looking for a DETAIL that isnt' specificly TOUR or TRIP, and then expected to map to it?

Comment: I don't know if I've got it that, but one DETAIL will have JUST one of parent tables, or its a detail of a tour or its a detail of a trip. I'm doing that to dont create two tables with the same columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of design, the SQL convention is that each relationship should have its own column in the referencing table. That's the concept if **foreign key** columns.

So you need to create two columns in each child table (DETAIL, COMMENT, MEDIA, PRICE), like `TOUR_ID` and `TRIP_ID` that will contain the primary key of the correspondig records in, respectively, tables `TOUR` and `TRIP`. Of course if a children refers to only one parent and not the other, only one column is necessary.

This will then allow you to build proper `JOIN` queries like :

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM TRIP
    JOIN DETAIL on DETAIL.TRIP_ID = TRIP.ID
    ...
WHERE
    ...
```